# Xml to Datagrid, Show lines from selected invoice

Tags: c#, vb.net

```
<Documents>
   <Sales>
    <Total>81678.600000</Total>
    <Invoice>
        <InvoiceNum>153</InvoiceNum>
        <Date>2013-03-01</Date>
        <Customer>2589</Customer>
        <Line>
            <ProductId>AT.02-2584</ProductId>
            <Description>Product 1</Description>
            <Quantity>1.000</Quantity>
            <UnitPrice>265.140000</UnitPrice>
        </Line>
    </Invoice>      
    <Invoice>
        <InvoiceNum>154</InvoiceNum>
        <Date>2013-03-01</Date>
        <Customer>2589</Customer>
        <Line>
            <ProductId>AT.02-2584</ProductId>
            <Description>Product 1</Description>
            <Quantity>1.000</Quantity>
            <UnitPrice>265.140000</UnitPrice>
        </Line>
                    <Line>
            <ProductId>AT.02-2599</ProductId>
            <Description>Product 2</Description>
            <Quantity>1.000</Quantity>
            <UnitPrice>85.100000</UnitPrice>
        </Line>
    </Invoice>  
</Sales>
```

I have this xml document, and i need show the lines (`<Line>` tag) when select an invoice in a datagridview. I have the following code, but only know how to show subelements of main element `"<Invoice>"`. How can query to show only `"<Line>"` elements for each `"<InvoiceNum>"` in datagrid:

```
filepath1 = "C:\Users\Documents\Teste.xml"
     Dim xml As XDocument = XDocument.Load(filepath1)

           Dim query = From xe In xml.Descendants("Invoice")
          Where xe.Element("InvoiceNum").Value = "153"
          Select New With {
             .Invoice = xe.Element("InvoiceNum").Value,
             .Date = xe.Element("Date").Value
          }
           DataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToArray
```

Comment: I dont get it, show just <Line> tag if you find it?
Whats the purpose of getting no info?
Can you put a example of output please?

Comment: I have another datagridview with all invoices in xml file. And i need when double click in selected invoice, view in another grid all lines from invoice.